# Input from Model not included in form POST data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a simple HTML POST form with a model contained within like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/pilotman/rn9gspz8/6/

note: the JS fiddle is basic and just for demo and is not perfect.

So when I submit the form and let the input inside the model has some text, my server script does not see 'input2'

```
$_POST['input2'];
```

Does the data inside the model get sent with the POST data from the form?
If not can it be done (I assume anything inside the form tag would be sent but I am clearly wrong)?

Thanks

Comment: your code is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. as per your jsfiddle

`$_POST['input1'];` is the normal input

`$_POST['input2'];` is the popup model input field;

[image]

Comment: I solved it. So I am also using frameworks and I found that I was appending the model to the body of the page and hence was not been included in form data :(